# Parallel LINQ over IAsyncEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-core, parallel-processing, plinq, iasyncenumerable

Any official or stable 3rd party library that supports using `AsParallel` over an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (.NET Standard 2.1) ?

I don't want to wrap an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` to an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` with async methods, `TaskCompletionSource` or something else because of extra cost.

Comment: Maybe you will need this. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/

Comment: @HoàngMinhThông It does support linq over `IAsyncEnumerable` and async selector/predicates, but `Parallel Linq` is another topic.